# Simple variation on factorial --- upper bound

Tags: co.combinatorics

Suppose $d$ is a constant $< n^2$, and $m > n$. I have a kind of factorial function where I subtract $d$ from each *pair* of terms.

Is there any simple upper bound on
$$
P = ( m (m-1) - d) \times ( (m-2) (m-3) - d ) \times \cdots \times \times ((n+1) n - d)
$$

I only need an polynomially tight upper bound. If it makes it easier, you can assume $m = cn$
 for $c$ close to 2.

The best I can come up with is
$$
P \leq \Bigl( \frac{m (m-1) - d}{m (m-1)} \Bigr)^{(m-n)/2} m!/n!
$$
but I don't think this is tight.

Thanks!

EDIT: Previous version incorrectly stated "exponentially tight" vs "polynomially tight"

Comment: You could pretend it is the product of m-n terms, half of them like m+k+sqrt(d) +1/2, the rest with a -sqrt(d) instead of +.  Gerhard "Email Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.06.21 

Comment: What do you mean by an “exponentially tight” upper bound? Your bound (as well as the trivial bound $m!/n!$) is tight up to a factor of $2^{O(m)}$, isn’t it?

Comment: @Emil, this was an error. I meant "polynomially tight"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit. Of course, I would find the mistake after posting.  k ranges over the even numbers from 2 to 2h, so the result is not as nice.  I will try rescuing the approach.   End Edit

Each term is close to (m- k+ sqrt(d) + 1/2)(m - k-  sqrt(d) + 1/2), where k ranges from 1 to h=(m-n)/2.  (h may be off by 1.) Your product is close to n! squared times the product of two binomial coefficients: m+ a choose h and m-  b choose h, where a anb are close to sqrt(d).  Letting a and b range over floor(sqrt(d)) and ceil(sqrt(d)) are a start if h is not too small.
For finer estimates, let a and b be appropriate real numbers.

Gerhard "Email Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.06.21

Comment: This formula works great. Thanks so much!

Comment: One can rescue it by dividng by 2^h and multiplying by 2^h, but that is not very satisfying.  Gerhard "Can Not Get No Satisfaction" Paseman, 2011.06.21 

Comment: David, I am glad you like the approach.  To make up for my earlier mistake, I offer to do a sanity check on any formula you post here addressing the problem and based on the method I suggested.  Good luck.  Gerhard "Email Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.06.21